# Change Float Button position in materialize css?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

[image]

As seen in below image i want to change the position to top upper corner of the page. Does anyone know how to manipulate this with any of the class available in materilaize css framework. The framework i am referring is :
http://materializecss.com/buttons.html

Answer (score 3):

`.fixed-action-btn` have right property change it as required to move it.

```
.fixed-action-btn{
right:50px;/*desired value*/
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 3):

In materialize.css, class `.fixed-action-btn` is declared as `right: 23px;`

In order to have your sticky button on left change `right: 23px` to `right: auto`

so you can write:

```
.fixed-action-btn{
                right: auto; 
                margin-left: 5%;  //optional
}
```